# JavaFX - creating custom dialogs using fxml

Tags: javafx, dialog

I'm new in javafx and I was trying to create custom dialogs/alerts. The thing is that I'm using Scene Builder to design the GUI, and I want to modify the dialog each time I load the fxml file (i.e change the title, label text, etc.), so I wanted to know if there's a way to send parameters and modify the stage/scene, or any other way I can achieve this.

To be more specific, let's say there's an error I want to handle anywhere in my program, so I load a new fxml file that represents the error dialog I created, and I modify the components inside it, depending on the type of error I need to handle, similar to, for example, JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(...) in swing.

Comment: Why not just use [`Alert`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Alert.html) or [`Dialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html)?

Comment: James_D, because I need all different design, and also every information should be in another language (not english)

Comment: Pretty sure they can do that, but I'll add an answer to address the more general question anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the use case you describe, you can just use the [`Dialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html) API, or the specialized [`Alert`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Alert.html) class that is part of that.

For the more general question you ask:

> I wanted to know if there's a way to send parameters and change the stage/scene

the way to do this is to use the [custom component](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components) mechanism described in the documentation.

In short, make a subclass of the UI type you need that loads the FXML file, and defines the properties you need, e.g.

```
public class ExceptionPane extends BorderPane {

    private final ObjectProperty<Exception> exception ;

    public ObjectProperty<Exception> exceptionProperty() {
        return exception ;
    }

    public final Exception getException() {
        return exceptionProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setException(Exception exception) {
        exceptionProperty().set(exception);
    }

    @FXML
    private final TextArea stackTrace ;
    @FXML
    private final Label message ;

    public ExceptionPane() throws Exception {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("path/to/fxml"));
        loader.setRoot(this);
        loader.setController(this);

        loader.load();

        exception.addListener((obs, oldException, newException) -> {
            if (newException == null) {
                message.setText(null);
                stackTrace.setText(null);
            } else {
                message.setText(newException.getMessage());
                StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                newException.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
                stackTrace.setText(sw.toString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then define the FXML using a ["dynamic root"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#root_elements):

```xml
<!-- imports etc -->

<fx:root type="BorderPane" ...>

    <center>
        <TextArea fx:id="stackTrace" editable="false" wrapText="false" />
    </center>
    <top>
        <Label fx:id="message" />
    </top>
</fx:root>
```

Now you can use this directly in either Java or in FXML:

```
try {
    // some code...
} catch (Exception exc) {
    ExceptionPane excPane = new ExceptionPane();
    excPane.setException(exc);
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setScene(new Scene(excPane));
    stage.show();
}
```

or

```xml
<fx:define fx:id="exc"><!-- define exception somehow --></fx:define>

<ExceptionPane exception="${exc}" />
```

Comment: is this the old version of fxml? my scene builder could not open the fxml if I put this into a file. it complains about the fx: prefix

Comment: @MaxiWu This is valid FXML. I know early versions of Scene Builder had trouble with `<fx:define>`; I haven't tried this with Scene Builder for a while. What version do you have?

Comment: I am using the latest one from GLUON. maybe I am missing some important <?imports>?

Comment: I modified to this and scenebuild works correctly.
https://gist.github.com/maxiwu/6e380706130ad79dc4bb346bc65b036c

Comment: now the ExceptionPane does pop up, but it is blank. I've checked the code, `message.setText()` is being called. newException.getMessage() is also correct. I don't know why the pane shows up blank.